# Regularity of Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

It is well known that given two measures $\nu$ and $\mu$ in, say, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded, if $\nu \ll \mu$ then $\exists f \in L^1 ( \Omega, d \mu)$ such that $\nu= f \mu$, and this $f$ is called the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$. In particular, if $\mu= |\nu|$ with $| \cdot |$ being the total variation, $f$ has also $\mu$-a.e. unitary norm and the above is called "polar decomposition". I was wondering: are there some non-trivial assumptions on the measure $\mu$ so that $f$ enjoys more regularity than being $L^1 \cap L^\infty$? I am particularly interested in the vector valued case of $\mu = \nabla g (x)  \mathcal{L}^d (dx)$. Of course if $g \in C^1$ then the $f$ is continuous, but I was wondering if more could be said when $g \in W^{1,p} (\Omega)$. Any reference is very welcome.

Comment: I changed $\nu<<\mu$ to $\nu\ll\mu.$ Enter "latex symbols" into a search engine and you find things like this.